# Search in data from many databases in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a huge database which has over 700 fields and over a million records. I need to implement a search function which retrieves records with the keyword in any field. Currently what I'm doing is to `CopyField` all the fields into a single field and perform searching on it. But it's slow.

The reason that there are so many fields is that they are from multiple databases. For example, there are fields `A1`, `A2` from database `A` and `B1`, `B2` from database `B`. And my schema looks like:

```
<field name="search_all" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true"/>
<field name="A1" class="solr.StrField" indexed="false"/>
<field name="A2" class="solr.StrField" indexed="false"/>
<field name="B1" class="solr.StrField" indexed="false"/>
<field name="B2" class="solr.StrField" indexed="false"/>

<copyField source="A1" dest="search_all"/>
<copyField source="A2" dest="search_all"/>
<copyField source="B1" dest="search_all"/>
<copyField source="B2" dest="search_all"/>
```

Because they are from multiple databases, there are a lot of empty fields in every records.

How can I optimize it?

Comment: What do you mean by word "slow" ? Import speed or search speed?

Comment: You can also use wildcards in copyfield definitions, so there's no need to have a copyfield instruction for every field.

Comment: @Oyeme I mean search speed

Comment: @MatsLindh But it's only a syntactic sugar, right?

Comment: @sqd It won't affect search speed, no. Search speed is usually down to the number of tokens, storage speed (ssd vs etc.), caches, warming queries, etc.

Comment: @sqd using solr UI interface you can tell us: do you have enough memory allocated to solr? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems